# Use Requests Module and return response to Pyspark Dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, python-requests

I'm hitting an API that sends a JSON response with two key:value pairs. I'm currently saving the response to my dataframe by hitting the API 2 different times and using withColumn to save each key:value pair to a column separately, instead of hitting the API once and saving both key:value pairs at once. Does anyone have guidance on how to do this properly?

My dataframe is one column that contains the values I ship to the API:

```
   businessId
    dksldfaw2
    kkldsdok3
    djdfkdfk3
    23lksdlk8
```

The JSON response:

```
{response:
FirstDataPoint: "SomethingSomething"
SecondDataPoint: "SomethingSomething"}
```

My code (which calls the API twice to parse one response):

```
def FirstVariableCode(businessId):
  response = api.query(id=businessId)
  x = response['FirstVariable'].encode('utf-8').strip()
  return x


def SecondVariableCode(businessId):
  response = api.query(id=businessId)
  y = response['SecondVariable'].encode('utf-8').strip()
  return y

FirstVariableCode = udf(FirstVariableCode, StringType())
SecondVariableCode = udf(SecondVariableCode, StringType())

df.withColumn('FirstVariable', FirstVariableCode(df.businessId))
df.withColumn('SecondVariable', SecondVariableCode(df.businessId))
```

How can I hit the API once and save both values to their respective columns correctly? I feel like I'm using 'withColumn' as a crutch and not doing this properly.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine both `udf` functions into one as

```
def variableCodes(businessId):
    response = api.query(id=businessId)
    x = response['FirstVariable'].encode('utf-8').strip()
    y = response['SecondVariable'].encode('utf-8').strip()
    return (x, y)

from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types as T
variableCodeUdf = F.udf(variableCodes, T.StructType([T.StructField("FirstVariable", T.StringType()), T.StructField('SecondVariable', T.StringType())]))
```

and then call the `udf` function once and the use `*` *to expand the struct column created by calling the udf function* into separate columns as

```
df.withColumn('variables', variableCodeUdf(df.businessId))\
    .select(F.col('businessId'), F.col('variables.*'))\
    .show(truncate=False)
```

This should give you `dataframe` something like below

```
+----------+-------------+--------------+
|businessId|FirstVariable|SecondVariable|
+----------+-------------+--------------+
|dksldfaw2 |x value1     |y1            |
|kkldsdok3 |x2           |y2            |
|djdfkdfk3 |x3           |y3            |
+----------+-------------+--------------+
```

I hope the answer is helpful

**Note: try to use inbuilt functions as much as possible instead of udf function**